# Can't type '|' {, }, | [ or ] in Firefox on the Macintosh (MBP, Swiss Keyboard)

Tags: mac, firefox, keyboard

I cannot type a **|** in Firefox. I had to cut and paste it in for this question.

On a Swiss Macintosh pressing the keys labeled <alt> <shift> and <7> producess a **|**, the 'vertical dash', sometimes called 'pipe' .. but not in FireFox.

The "keyboard viewer" agrees...

Entering **[** or **]** using <alt-5> and <alt-6> also doesn't work, but  <alt-shift-5> and <alt-shift-6> do.

**{** and **}** are also "broken" (=not what I expected) in FireFox.

Is this a known issue? and is there a solution?

I did google, but don't seem to find search terms google understands ... **{**, **}**, **|** and **[** or **]** are all ignored ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now there doesn't seem to be a way to enter those keys into firefox other than cut & paste.

I'll update this question should I find a usable (intuitive & quick) approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the official [Firefox shortcut list](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts). Sadly, it is also said on the same page that those shortcut cannot be changed.

```
Back: Cmd + [
Forward: Cmd + ]
Previous Tab: Cmd + {
Next Tab: Cmd + }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a Plugin is capturing some keyboard inputs. I would try disabling all Plugins and restarting Firefox to see whether the problem persists, then re-enabling them until you figure out which one causes the problem.